# White Screen error When running script

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to run a script for my website and I am getting a white screen with no errors, I have tried running the script with

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',TRUE);
```

But I still get no errors, I do not have access the php.ini as I am using a godaddy.

```
//Get ITID from URL
$iITID = $_GET["ITID"];

$oteaminfo = mysql_query("
SELECT .Players.FirstName, Players.LastName, Players.Position, Players.Height,                    Players.Weight, .Players.DOB, Countries.Nation, NHLTeams.Team,      ;  ; ; InternationalTeam.InternationalTeam, InternationalLeagues.InternationLeague,    CNGHLTeams.CNGHLRights
From Players
Inner Join InternationalTeam
On Players.ITID=InternationalTeam.ITID
Inner Join InternationalLeagues
On Players.ILID=InternationalLeagues.ILID
Inner Join Countries
On Players.NationID=Countries.NationID
Inner Join NHLTeams
On Players.TeamsID=NHLTeams.TeamID
Inner Join CNGHLTeams
On Players.CNGHLID=CNGHLTeams.CNGHLID
WHERE InternationalTeam.InternationalTeam=$iITID
ORDER BY Players.LastName;
") or die(mysql_error()); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($oteaminfo)) 
{ 
Print "Player Name: ".$row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName']."<br>"; 
Print "Position: ".$row['Position']."<br>"; 
Print "Height: ".$row['Height']."<br>"; 
Print "Weight: ".$row['Weight']."<br>"; 
Print "Birthdate: ".$row['DOB']."<br>"; 
Print "Nationality: ".$row['NationID']."<br>";
Print "NHL Rights: ".$row['Team']."<br>";
Print "CNGHL Team: ".$row['CNGHLRights']."<br>"; 
} 


  ?>
```

The script is missing `Players.Weight, .Players.DOB, Countries.Nation, NHLTeams.Team, InternationalTeam.InternationalTeam, InternationalLeagues.InternationLeague,    CNGHLTeams.CNGHLRights`

As it wont let me indent it to show up as script.  I have tried looking up this issue but I cannot seem to find anything that will help me in my situation.  Any Help would be wonderful thanks.

Comment: Have you created a MySQL connection? Also, perhaps your query does not return any rows

Comment: If turning on `error_reporting` and `display_errors` still result in a white screen then it's usually a startup error. Check the logs for your site, or try running the script from the command line to see what the errors are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is the beginning of your SQL

```
SELECT .Players.FirstName, Players.LastName, Players.Position
```

that is messing up. The corrected SQL should be like

```
SELECT Players.FirstName, Players.LastName, Players.Position
```

And, as you are attempting to print results on a page, preferably use `echo` than `print`. And, `print` should be `print` and not `Print`. PHP is case sensitive.

Also, as per PHP Manual, `mysql_` commands are deprecated. It is preferable to use `mysqli_` commands or PDO.

Comment: PHP functions and language constructs are not case sensitive. `Print` is fine.

Comment: Should use brackets though, since print is an actual function unlike echo;

Comment: @OlegTikhonov No it isn't. [*print is not actually a real function (it is a language construct) so you are not required to use parentheses with its argument list.*](http://php.net/manual/function.print.php)

Comment: but it behaves as one, and if you want to call it recursively or pass it as a parameter you can do that

Answer (score 0):

Try ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
Basically since the latest release of PHP you can define error visibility per each level, but this line should do it.

Let me know if it helps, if not I might rewrite your code using PDO and try - catch blocks, this way you will be able to raise an exception, and generally your code will be more secure.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Hi There,thanks for your help. I changed the error code but I am still getting the same result. Godaddy uses SQL version 5.0.  I am pretty new at this so working through the debugs have been a bit of a challenge for me, when it gives me errors I can usually work through them but the blank screen stumped me.

Comment: I think any *truthy* value will work except for some special cases

Comment: You should try the revision that Phil offered, also print() is a function, not a statement, you should use brackets and lower case with it.

Alternatively you can use echo "string";